# How can I create a @ sign using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flickr

I am creating a variable that contains a string that uses the @ symbol. How can I do this in Javascript without the @ sign being parsed as something different in the url?

Comment: I don't understand... `var x = "mystring@test"` will work just fine

Comment: What is so special about `@` that you can't just put it in a string? Based on your tags, are you trying to fetch pictures from Flickr? If yes, then try this: `encodeURIComponent(abc@example.com)`

Comment: Are you asking how to URL encode an `@` in a string that will be used for a URL, so the URL will only include safe characters (like URL encoding a blank space with `+`, for instance)? If so, refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/332872/1306809).

Comment: question sounds silly without any context. If you are having a problem...explain what the the problem is

Answer (score 5):

You're probably constructing a URL by concatenating strings:

```
var ajax_url = 'foo.json?' + key + '=' + value;
```

Don't do that. Use jQuery's AJAX functions and pass an object instead:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'foo.json',
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false, // You might need that
    data: {
        key: value
    },
    success: function(data) {
        ...
    }
});
```

`key` and `value` will automatically be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

`@` is not a special character in strings in JavaScript. If you need it in a string, just put it in the string as you would any other normal character.

Answer (score -1):

Is it /@ or @@? Those are typically conventions used in other languages.